# is it possible to set HTTP Headers using Azure Powershell (ISE)?

Tags: powershell, http-headers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm looking for a way to set HTTP Headers using scripting, can it be done in Azure Powershell (Powershell ISE Azure module)? I could not find the mention setting http headers using Powershell.

I don't code in languages like C# or Php nor JS.

Current tools I use (Cloudberry, Cerebrata AMS, Zud.io) are not allowing me to set and retain http header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*" even after I've enabled CORS. Therefore I need to find another way to set headers in Azure-Storage blobs.

What are my options ?

Comment: @Hyper Anthony, Azure-powershell is an available tool, could you please clarify why you edited my tag out ?

Comment: I didn't remove any tags? I added the tag 'azure-powershell' because you are specifically asking about the azure powershell module. Tagging the question as such will alert users that are subscribed to 'azure-powershell' to view the question.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the tracked change. Thank you!